# "No root element" error when processing a web service within SSIS script

Tags: c#, ssis-2012

I am trying to write an SSIS job that will process XML files obtained from a vendor.  I looked online and found some code that met my needs.  I modified it to handle the XML and ran it.  I am getting the error "System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing."  I am not sure what I did wrong.  The c# code is:

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    //Set Webservice URL
    string wUrl = "https://digitalmeasures.com/login/service/v4/Role";

    try
    {
        //Call getWebServiceResult to return our DailyStat array
        Roles outPutStats = GetWebServiceResult(wUrl);

        //For each group of metrics output records
        foreach (var stats in outPutStats.thisRole)
        {

            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            Output0Buffer.roleKey = stats.roleKey;
            Output0Buffer.text = stats.text;
            Output0Buffer.Item = stats.Item;
            Output0Buffer.Users = stats.Users;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        FailComponent(e.ToString());
    }
}

private Roles GetWebServiceResult(string wUrl)
{

    HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(wUrl);
    httpWReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password")));
    HttpWebResponse httpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

    Roles xmlResponse = null;

    try
    {
        //Test the connection
        if (httpWResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {

            Stream responseStream = httpWResp.GetResponseStream();

            //Set xmlString using a stream reader
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                //Deserialize our XML
                XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Roles));
                xmlResponse = (Roles)sr.Deserialize(reader);
                reader.Close();
            }

        }
        //Output connection error message
        else
        {
            FailComponent(httpWResp.StatusCode.ToString());

        }
    }
    //Output xml parsing error
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        FailComponent(e.ToString());
    }
    return xmlResponse;

}

private void FailComponent(string errorMsg)
{
    bool fail = false;
    IDTSComponentMetaData100 compMetadata = this.ComponentMetaData;
    compMetadata.FireError(1, "Error Getting Data From Webservice!", errorMsg, "", 0, out fail);

}
}

   public class Role
{
    public string roleKey { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public string Users { get; set; }
}

[XmlRootAttribute("Roles")]
public class Roles
{
    [XmlElement("Role")]
    public Role[] thisRole { get; set; }
}
```

The XML I am processing is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Roles xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:immutable="http://www.digitalmeasures.com/schema/immutable">
    <immutable:Role roleKey="INDIVIDUAL-ACTIVITIES-University-DataBackupService" text="Data Backup Service">
        <Item xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="/login/service/v4/Role/INDIVIDUAL-ACTIVITIES-University-DataBackupService"/>
        <Users xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="/login/service/v4/RoleUser/INDIVIDUAL-ACTIVITIES-University-DataBackupService"/>
    </immutable:Role>
    <Role roleKey="INDIVIDUAL-ACTIVITIES-University-DepartmentUpdatePrimaryAssignmentOrg" text="Department: Update Primary Assignment Org">
        <Item xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="/login/service/v4/Role/INDIVIDUAL-ACTIVITIES-University-DepartmentUpdatePrimaryAssignmentOrg"/>
        <Users xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="/login/service/v4/RoleUser/INDIVIDUAL-ACTIVITIES-University-DepartmentUpdatePrimaryAssignmentOrg"/>
    </Role>
</Roles>
```

Comment: the XML does not contain a root element. an element that starts it, and ends it.

Comment: Isn't that the <Roles></Roles> combo?  My knowledge of XML isn't extensive.

Comment: no a root element is unique - out of wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element `Each XML document has exactly one single root element. It encloses all the other elements and is therefore the sole parent element to all the other elements.`

Comment: There's only one <Roles> tag, or am I missing something?

Comment: you are correct. i failed to see the 's' in roles. are you positiv ethis is the exact XML your processing ?

Comment: Yes.  I cut out a few lines for brevity.  That's why I'm confused on the error I'm getting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144072/discussion-between-michael-robinson-and-stavm).